# SAML authentication for Jupyter Hub

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, jupyter, okta, jupyterhub

I should implement **SAML** authentication (Okta) in Jupyter. I have tried to search but didn't find anything. Maybe someone knows the solution. Thanks for help.

Comment: Hey, did you figure this out in the end?

Comment: Hey, do you mean you want to extend JupyterHub functionality (and make it available for others)?

Comment: @Avision I will send a reply when it will be done. I haven't done it yet.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to add Single Sign On to Jupyterhub via Okta, then I strongly suggest taking advantage of [OpenID Connect](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/oauth2.html). This will be *much* easier than adding SAML support.

If you need to implement SAML specifically, the typical way would be to use PySAML2, I wrote a [detailed guide for adding SAML support to Python/Flask](http://developer.okta.com/code/python/pysaml2).

However, it looks like Jupyterhub uses Tornado and also appears that [PySAML2 doesn't work with Tornado](https://github.com/rohe/pysaml2/issues/235). If you are looking to add SAML support to Jupyter hub and you are feeling very adventurous, then another avenue to investigate would be to implement your own SAML validation using [signxml](https://github.com/XML-Security/signxml).

Answer (score 1):

You should try using the jupyterhub-samlauthenticator.

Check it out here: https://github.com/bluedatainc/jupyterhub-samlauthenticator